# The Virtual keyboard and the slow loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard

I tried to add a virtual keyboard to my code using jQuery, in fact I have several text fields and I added to each on this keyboard.
My problem is when I load the page it take a lot of times (~ 10 seconds) to display.

This is my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/TUAHC/12/).

Code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("Table-1");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

for(var i=0;i<150;i++) {   
row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.name = "animate";
cell1.id = i ;
var values = document.createElement("input");                
values.type = "text" ;
cell1.appendChild(values);
rowCount++;            
}

$('input[type=text]').keyboard({
  layout: "qwerty"
});
```

​

Comment: because it is 150 elements be appended via a for loop.

Comment: Use your browser's profiler/dev tools to figure out for yourself why it's slow.

Comment: Reuse a single keyboard, don't create 150 of them, that's where the delay is rather than the loop which is trivial.

Comment: Yes ALex, this is the problem, I try to use one keyboard but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first solution to my problem ; I only call the keyboard when I click in the text box.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/TUAHC/13/).

But it's still a bit slow...

Code :

```
var table = document.getElementById("Table-1");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

for(var i=0;i<150;i++) {   
row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.name = "animate";
cell1.id = i ;
var values = document.createElement("input");                
values.type = "text" ;
cell1.appendChild(values);
rowCount++;    

$('#'+i).click(function() {
         $('input[type=text]').keyboard({
      layout: "qwerty"
   });
});

}
```